# Saving multiple plots in R based on different datasets in one PDF

Tags: r, pdf

I am really a beginner and have seen answers on Stackoverflow for plots in the same dataset but not plots based on multiple sets.
I have a dataset with 100 small datasets (100 paintings), and these paintings have been rated from 1-4 by 30 participants. So I get one plot per painting and I would like them all save in one PDF. How can I do this in one go or not by hand for each plot?

The dataset looks like this:

```
painting_no measurement participant
1           3           1
1           4           2
1           3           3
1           2           4
...         ...         ...
```

I first created the small datasets like this:

```
pai1   <- subset(SeaAWIDE, SeaAWIDE$painting_no =="1")
pai2   <- subset(SeaAWIDE, SeaAWIDE$painting_no =="2")
pai3   <- subset(SeaAWIDE, SeaAWIDE$painting_no =="3")
pai4   <- subset(SeaAWIDE, SeaAWIDE$painting_no =="4")
```

And only after creating the small datasets did I create the barplots like this:

```
barplot(table(pai1$measurement),   ylab='Frequency', ylim=c(0,30), main= 'Painting 1 ') 
barplot(table(pai2$measurement),   ylab='Frequency', ylim=c(0,30), main= 'Painting 2 ')
barplot(table(pai3$measurement),   ylab='Frequency', ylim=c(0,30), main= 'Painting 3 ')
barplot(table(pai4$measurement),   ylab='Frequency', ylim=c(0,30), main= 'Painting 4 ')
```

This does produce the plots in the r window, which I could save manually and copy into a single file - but is there a code which will save these barplots automatically in one file? It could either save these already produced barplots or rewrite the code as a function looping over the painting numbers

Comment: The `pdf` output device should be able to do that. Read: `?Devices` and `?pdf`

Comment: R has support for LaTeX. You should look into it if you are insterested in wrinting a paper in R which includes graphics that are going to be updated when you change the data instead of copy and pasting static images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pdf` function redirects the graphical output to a specified file.  You use `dev.off` to close the device and have the output sent to the R window again.  The code looks like this:

```
pdf("path\filename.pdf", height = 8, width = 8) # change height and width as needed for good results
barplot(table(pai1$measurement),   ylab='Frequency', ylim=c(0,30), main= 'Painting 1 ') 
barplot(table(pai2$measurement),   ylab='Frequency', ylim=c(0,30), main= 'Painting 2 ')
# ...
dev.off()
```

But you can simplify this greatly by putting everything in a single command.

```
painting_data <- split(SeaAWIDE, SeaAWIDE$painting_no)

library(purrr) # walk function
pdf("path\filename.pdf", height = 8, width = 8)
walk(1:length(painting_data), function(i) {
   barplot(
     table(painting_data[[i]]$measurement),
     ylab='Frequency',
     ylim=c(0,30),
     main= paste('Painting',i)
   )
})
dev.off()
```